# WSDL2Java Throws Could not find main class: org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I am trying to create the java files from a remote webservice. I downloaded axis 1.4, copied the lib folder to `c:\data\axis\lib` which contains of these files:

- axis.jar
- axis-ant.jar
- commons-discovery-0.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- jaxrpc.jar
- log4j.properties
- log4j-1.2.8.jar
- saaj.jar
- wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

I added the `c:\data\axis\lib` folder to the `%AXISCLASSPATH%`. Now I am trying to create the java classes using this cmd:

```
java -cp %AXISCLASSPATH% org.apache.wsdl.WSDL2JAVA http://myurl.com?wsdl
```

However I keep getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/wsdl/
WSDL2Java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java.  Program will exit.
```

Can someone help me to get this working?

Comment: you should have common filenames those are in bat file and copying path. Additionally make sure that saaj.jar is axis-saaj.jar

Comment: jar is missing means you also need to rename jars if required.

Answer (score 6):

Add the jars to the classpath individually if you're using a Java version before 6.  If you're using Java 6, see [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) if you want to use wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
java -cp %AXISCLASSPATH% org.apache.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://myurl.com?wsdl
```

Class names are case sensitive

Comment: I used axis2 and it worked fine. However how do I now use the service file in my java file? I tried adding the import net.mycompany.myservice however I get package does not exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Login as eucalyptis and compile and it will find all of the jars - this took me forever to figure out!

Comment: Where should he login?

Answer (score 0):

package structure is wrong. Please use org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java